# Debug PHP web page in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

How do I run a PHP web page in Eclipse? I am using [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/).

I was able to do this when I was studying Java EE. I just hit run and then Eclipse's built in browser shows and you can run the website already.

Right now I am able to do this by putting my PHP files in the folder that Apache serves and then I open my browser and go the php file I created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf